# Prerequisites for the DCOM Proxy to connect DCOM Application in aremote machine through impersonate

Tags: c++, proxy, com, visual-c++-6, dcom

We have a DCOM application with lots of methods to business with. The application is written in VC6 and running fine and deployed as a DLL.

When called from the machine where the DCOM DLL is hosted(DCOM Server), the App that uses the DCOM stuff working fine.

EDIT 4:
The DCOM Application is hosted with the following properties

[image]

The problem is with the distributed deployment, where the proxy of the DCOM application is exported(through the Export as Proxy from DCOMCNFG), and installed in another PC(DCOM Client). In this scenario, the DCOM Test App is not working.

On checking the prerequisites, we found the following conditions

1. Both DCOM Server and Client have to be in the same WORKGROUP or
   Domain (both PC is now in same WORKGROUP)
2. Both PC must be reachable
3. Appropriate Firewall exceptions to be added or firewall in both the
   PC or need to be turned off
4. Both the PC must have a login with same user name and password(One User named 'demoUser' was created in both the PC with same password)

**We made all the prerequisites and still the application is not working :(**

Are we missing anything or any setting?

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:** The Test Application is failing on creating of Object itself when tried in the Client Side.

**EDIT 2:** [Solved] Error

[image: Error and Error Code]

EDIT 3:
When putting both the PCs in the same subnet(there was a Hardware Firewall between the Subnets), solved the above issue.

[New Error] If both the PC are logged in with the same user with same password the application is working, though in WORKGROUP. But if the password is changed in any PC, the Application is throwing the following error.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'MyDCOM.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'MyDCOM.IApplication'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{18B31ADE-04BF-445A-ADE9-0984EBF49D8F}' failed due to the following error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

Comment: "Remote Procedure Call(RPC)" is running in both the PCs. There is another service called "Remote Procedure Call(RPC) Locator". Is that need to be started too?

Comment: The Firewall is completely off in all the PCs.

Comment: I have tried multiple restarts of the PCs too :( Is this to do anything with any setting in Group Policy?